# Multiple entry Schengen Visa query for Portugal

Tags: visas, schengen, portugal

We recently visited the Netherlands in November 2019, my wife applied for a Schengen visa and was given a multple entry visa which stated schengenstaten. This visa was from November 2019 to November 2020. We were in Netherlands for 3 days

We are planning on visiting Lisbon towards the end of next month, but we are unsure whether my wife will need to apply for schengen visa again. We are planning on staying in Portugal for 6 days. VFS Global are saying it should be fine but are also saying as a precaution I should contact the Portuguese consulate to confirm however, I am having an extremely difficult time contacting them and I live 3 hours away from their location in the UK.

Would anyone happen to know if this will be okay?

Thanks